# Overlap 3 images and center them in fluid container

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to overlap 3 images and center them within a twitter bootstrap row-fluid div.  Here is an example of what it should look like:
[image]

The solution can use javascript but I'd prefer if it didn't.  Also, when the browser is resized the images should remain in the center of Div 1.  Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overlaping:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

To center them, use `margin-left` and `margin-right:auto`, as long as the parent has a fixed width.

Comment: Can you please provide an example.  The left/right margin auto does not work with what I have so far.  Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikt25/m59GX/).

Comment: margin:0 auto; is a property of the images, not of the container.

Comment: Quick fix: Add text-align:center; to your .imgcontainer selector.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you for your help.  If you link to the fiddle in your answer or link to your own with modifications, (if you think anything could be done better) I will accept your answer.

Comment: Certainly: http://jsfiddle.net/uQbaf/ . All you have to do is position your images as you like.

Comment: It would be better to edit that link into your original answer so people don't have to read all the comments, but either way... Answer accepted.  Thanks again!